# Disable "1 question with new activity" highlighting - PLEASE

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro

I have programmers as a pinned tab. Since some hours I got it highlighted that keeps blinking.
First I thought of a bug in chrome but than I saw this message which was totally new for me:

> 1 question with new activity

Every time this kind of message appears on the top of the question list, my tab starts blinking.

I am way too often in my browser to get such an extreme low priority information (so low that using the word priority is way too much).

A chat should use the highlighting of a tab when someone "pinged" me (which the chat does) but please not a regular SE site!

I searched and can't find a way do disable that. If this "feature" stay, I need to remove programmers from my standard open tabs... this drives me nuts!

Comment: I'm looking at Programmers and Stack Overflow and the only thing that's happening is a (n) appearing before the site title in the tab and a little banner on the site homepage. I don't see any flashing or blinking...

Comment: Yep, the feature is kind of annoying. Stack overflow is not the urgent type of site that should be nagging about constant updates, IMHO. Even "(n) new questions" bugs me a little.

Comment: It's also doing this in FireFox when you pin the tab. I thought it was a neat feature personally. I guess the way to "fix" it would be to have the question notification pop-up be a user preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not do anything explicit with regards to flashing.  This may be default browser behavior but not any we have experienced thus far.  Do you have any plugins that make the browser flash in chat?  We use the same method as chat where we change the title of the page based on the number of new active posts.

Comment: Seems that Chrome highlights the tab that changes the title but only when it is pinned. Why does Programmers do this?

Comment: @WarrenFaith That sounds like a Chrome feature (or bug, depending on how you look at it). I see no highlighting, flashing, or blinking on my Chrome on any network site. But then again, I don't pin tabs.